# Hardhat get deployed contract

Tags: solidity, hardhat

So I am using hardhat-deploy plugin and I have only 2 contracts to deploy.

```
01 - token
02 - someActionContract
```

`02 - someActionContract` is able to mint tokens, so it requires to know the address of a token to mint. So I can find it manually after both deployed, but I want to make it during deployment. So once token is deployed, I could pass it's address to someActionContract args. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { ethers } from "hardhat"

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners()

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")
    const token = await Token.deploy()
    await token.deployed()
    console.log("Token Contract Address : ", token.address)

    const SomeActionContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("SomeActionContract")
    // Deploy some contract and pass token.address if you doing it via Constructor
    const someActionContract = await Token.deploy(token.address)
    await someActionContract.deployed()

    console.log("someActionContract Contract Address : ", someActionContract.address)
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exitCode = 1
})
```

```
npx hardhat run ./scripts/deploy.ts or deploy.js
```

Comment: hey, that's not hardhat-deploy, that's a universal deploy script, it doesn't suits my needs

Comment: Sorry , can you provide more details ?  I was thinking you have a problem with hardhat deployment.

Comment: We are talking about this plugin - https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy

Comment: did you try this: https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy#hardhat-deploy-in-a-nutshell? it should be something like this:  args: [token.address]

Answer (score 1):

In this second deployment file, you can retrieve your deployed contract and then get the address and abi like so:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

module.exports = async function({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments;
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();

    const token = await hre.deployments.get('Token');
    const address = token.address;
    const abi = token.abi;
    const ARGS = [ address ];

    const someActionContract = await deploy('SomeActionContract', {
        from: deployer,
        args: ARGS,
        log: true,
    });
}
module.exports.tags = ['someActionContract'];
```